# Using pythons parse with criteria

Tags: python, findall

First of all I got to say that I have very little experience with any sort of coding so even I dont completely know what Im after here, but Im trying my best!

Ive been writing this code that takes the HTML of a certain website and then gives me .CSV file of the elements(?) that are named  (you can see these in the inspect panel of the website).

So my question is, how can I use criteria with my current code so I can tell the code to only return words with, for example, the letter g in them?

Im happy to elaborate!
Thank you already!

```
    import urllib.request
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import csv
    
    url = 'https://kouluruoka.fi/menu/kouvola_koulujenruokalista'
    
    request = urllib.request.Request(url)
    
    content = urllib.request.urlopen(request)
    
    parse = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    

    #These texts get words in <h2> and <span> named elements

    text1 = parse.find_all('h2')
    
    text2 = parse.find_all('span')

    
    #This code uses the texts above to create the .CSV file

    with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
      writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
      for col1,col2 in zip(text1, text2):
        writer.writerow([col1.get_text().strip(), col2.get_text().strip()])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if elements contains some string/letter this way:

```
h2_elements = parse.find_all('h2')
span_elements = parse.find_all('span')
# This code uses the texts above to create the .CSV file

with open('index.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    for h2_element, span_element in zip(h2_elements, span_elements):
        h2_element_str = h2_element.get_text().strip()
        span_element_str = span_element.get_text().strip()

        if 'a' in h2_element_str and 'a' in span_element_str:
            writer.writerow([h2_element_str, span_element_str])
```

Comment: Thank you!

How do I change it to be a list? So if I want the ones with A and B? Tried ['A','B'] but apparently it doesnt quite work like that..

Oh and can I also somehow add other crietira like after it checks if the elements have A or B in them and then checks if those elemenst have 1 or 2 in them and EXCLUDES those? So the elemnst that would be left would be the ones with A or B, and of those only the ones without 1 and 2.

Thank you again!